# Update variable in __init__ if dependency has changed

Tags: python, oop

Having a class like

```
 class C():
    
    def __init__(self, bits: list):

       self.bits = bits
       self.values = [bit.value for bit in self.bits]

c = C(bits)
```

If I update  `c.bits`
,  `c.values`
wont change. How can I achieve that also  `c.values`
is updatet?

Comment: I think you have an error in this line: `self.bits = list` - wasn't it supposed to be `self.bits = bits`?

Comment: @matszwecja sure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If values is supposed to be dependant on the value of bits **at all times**, don't store it as a separate object, instead make a function that will return current values. If you use @property decorator, you can even use it like a normal attribute in the code.

```
class C():
    def __init__(self, bits: list):
       self.bits = bits
    @property
    def values(self):
       return[bit.value for bit in self.bits]
c = C(bits)
print(c.values)
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for:)